# Getting the following error "Error when checking target: expected dense_11 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ( )" For loop LSTM

Tags: keras

When I am trying to run the LSTM inside the for loop I am getting this error.

I am giving one single data input to train and test the model.

I have 1000 rows of data.

Can anyone kindly help me to do this, Thank you in advance